How to tokenize a text in Google Spreadsheet
I have a cell (D2) in Google Sheets containing a title, and I want to extract everything up to the first punctuation mark (if any) and display it in another cell.
Example
For example, if D2 contains:
"This is a test. And this the second."
I want the result to be:
"This is a test."
What I tried
I tried using functions like REGEXEXTRACT and FIND but keep getting errors.
Can anyone help me with a formula that works without errors, even if there's no punctuation?

It is recommended that you provide the error you get as well.

A search on [google-sheets] extract text finds similar questions, didn't they help?
Extract text between two characters, Extract text between quotation marks, REGEXEXTRACT extract text

In most spreadsheet applications those common 4 function categories help to extract text:

FIND to find a text portion or character with its position
LEFT, RIGTH and MID to cut a number of characters from beginning, end and mid
SPLIT to split a text by a delimiting character or text
regex functions like REGEXTRACT for Google Sheets (also in MS Excel, but in LibreOffice Calc called REGEX)

See in the next section how to apply them to extract text.
Three ways to extract text up to any period character
Given a cell with text, from which you want the first sentence before a period. Expected result: This is a test.



A1




This is a test. And this the second.



To extract text until the . character you can use one of these 3 ways:

the traditional find & cut pattern,
an easy and very expressive SPLIT function, and
the more complex but very flexible regular expression function.

1. FIND and then LEFT
Already answered by Ed Nelson.
Only works if the character (here the period) is found, because FIND returns #VALUE! if not found!
=LEFT(A1, FIND(".", A1)-1)

In the formula we need to subtract the length parameter by one (the -1 at the end) since we don't want the period extracted.
Works for:
This is a test. And this the second.

But not for:
This is a test and this the second

Here it returns #VALUE! and we have to use IFERROR to return the complete cell text as default alternative:
=IFERROR( LEFT(A1, FIND(".", A1)-1), A1 )

2. SPLIT
=SPLIT(A1, '.')

Splits the text in cell A1 by a character or text (here period) into multiple adjacent cells like



B1
C1




This is a test
And this the second



Can use it with INDEX to get only the first part into one cell:
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"."),1)

See explained answer: Google Sheets: extract text between two characters.
3. REGEXTRACT
=REGEXTRACT(A1, "^(.*)\.")

Finds any text (.*) between the beginning ^ and the period \. (since special-character escaped with backslash) and extracts it. The extraction is indicated by the surrounding parentheses that form the so called capture-group.
To make it work with an absent period, we have to tell the regex to make the period an optional character. See Regex Tutorial - The Question Mark Makes the Preceding Token Optional.
=REGEXTRACT(A1, "^(.*)\.?")

See explained answer: Extract text between brackets using google spreadsheets.
See also

Regex find value between a space and period for Google Sheet
replace everything after a character in Google spreadsheet


Try:
=Left(D2,find(".",D2,1)-1)
